# What causes "broken pipe" when using Jetty Content Exchange and SSL?

Tags: java, jetty

I am trying to make a http request using the Jetty Content Exchange object and am getting the following error.

What does the handshake failure mean exactly, and how can I get more informative logs on what exactly is failing?

```
15:53:57.765 [qtp88119371-18] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] Flushed 37/37
15:53:57.765 [qtp88119371-18] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] unwrap filled 0
15:53:57.765 [qtp88119371-18] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] unwrap filled 0
15:53:57.765 [qtp88119371-18] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] unwrap filled 0
15:53:57.765 [qtp88119371-18] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] unwrap filled 0
15:53:57.765 [qtp88119371-18] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] unwrap filled 0
15:53:57.765 [qtp88119371-18] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] unwrap filled 0
15:53:57.765 [qtp88119371-18] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] unwrap filled 0
15:53:57.765 [qtp88119371-18] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] unwrap filled 0
15:53:57.765 [qtp88119371-18] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] unwrap filled 0
15:53:57.811 [qtp88119371-19] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] unwrap filled 7
15:53:57.811 [qtp88119371-19] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] closing NEED_WRAP
15:53:57.811 [qtp88119371-19] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl - [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] close wrap Status = CLOSED HandshakeStatus = NEED_UNWRAP
bytesConsumed = 0 bytesProduced = 23
15:53:57.814 [qtp88119371-19] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - EXCEPTION 
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.write0(Native Method) [na:1.6.0_26]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:29) [na:1.6.0_26]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:72) [na:1.6.0_26]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:28) [na:1.6.0_26]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:334) [na:1.6.0_26]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:229) [jetty-io-7.4.2.v20110526.jar:7.4.2.v20110526]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.flush(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:282) [jetty-io-7.4.2.v20110526.jar:7.4.2.v20110526]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslSelectChannelEndPoint.flush(SslSelectChannelEndPoint.java:638) [jetty-io-7.4.2.v20110526.jar:7.4.2.v20110526]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslSelectChannelEndPoint.sslClose(SslSelectChannelEndPoint.java:224) [jetty-io-7.4.2.v20110526.jar:7.4.2.v20110526]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslSelectChannelEndPoint.close(SslSelectChannelEndPoint.java:313) [jetty-io-7.4.2.v20110526.jar:7.4.2.v20110526]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint.fill(ChannelEndPoint.java:187) [jetty-io-7.4.2.v20110526.jar:7.4.2.v20110526]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslSelectChannelEndPoint.unwrap(SslSelectChannelEndPoint.java:695) [jetty-io-7.4.2.v20110526.jar:7.4.2.v20110526]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslSelectChannelEndPoint.flush(SslSelectChannelEndPoint.java:559) [jetty-io-7.4.2.v20110526.jar:7.4.2.v20110526]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslSelectChannelEndPoint.flush(SslSelectChannelEndPoint.java:489) [jetty-io-7.4.2.v20110526.jar:7.4.2.v20110526]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:849) [jetty-http-7.4.2.v20110526.jar:7.4.2.v20110526]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:235) [jetty-client-7.4.2.v20110526.jar:7.4.2.v20110526]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:535) [jetty-io-7.4.2.v20110526.jar:7.4.2.v20110526]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40) [jetty-io-7.4.2.v20110526.jar:7.4.2.v20110526]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:529) [jetty-util-7.4.2.v20110526.jar:7.4.2.v20110526]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [na:1.6.0_26]
15:53:57.818 [qtp88119371-19] WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - 50.17.212.38:443 javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
15:53:57.818 [qtp88119371-19] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Failure on GetAvailability@296737228=GET//XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:443/health#4
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:911)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:535)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:529)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:190)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1429)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1397)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1563)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1023)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:837)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:713)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:607)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslSelectChannelEndPoint.unwrap(SslSelectChannelEndPoint.java:755)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslSelectChannelEndPoint.flush(SslSelectChannelEndPoint.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslSelectChannelEndPoint.flush(SslSelectChannelEndPoint.java:489)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.flushBuffer(HttpGenerator.java:849)
        ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Broken pipe' means you have written to a connection that has already been closed by the other end. Typically you sent something it didn't understand and it closed the connection in mute protest. In this case I would wonder whether it really was an SSL service at the target host:port.

Comment: So you say mute protest, am I correct in assuming that unless I have access to logs of this server I am stuck with trial and error?

Comment: @UsmanIsmail unless Jetty's SSL provides some more tracing, I guess so. Try it in plaintext. What port number were you connecting to? The HTTPS ports are usually 443 or 8443. Check your Jetty configuration to make sure you have the correct port for HTTPS.

Comment: It was a certificate problem the certificate root was not trusted by my client.